# Append to a vector in a function

Tags: clojure

I have two columns (vectors) of different length and want to create a new vector of rows (if the column has enough elements). I'm trying to create a new vector (see failed attempt below). In Java this would involve the steps: iterate vector, check condition, append to vector, return vector. Do I need recursion here? I'm sure this is not difficult to solve, but it's very different than procedural code.

```
(defn rowmaker [colA colB]
  "create a row of two columns of possibly different length"
  (let [mia (map-indexed vector colA)
        rows []]
    (doseq [[i elA] mia]
        ;append if col has enough elements
       (if (< i (count colA)) (vec (concat rows elA)))  ; ! can't append to rows
       (if (< i (count colB)) (vec (concat rows (nth colB i)))
    ;return rows   
    rows)))
```

Expected example input/output

```
(rowMaker ["A1"] ["B1" "B2"])
; => [["A1" "B1“] [“" "B2"]]
```

Comment: `elB` is what?  could you also please add a possible example of the data your sending in and ideally an example, what the outcome would look like.  it makes writing an answer alot easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn rowMaker [colA colB]
  "create a row from two columns"
  (let [ca (count colA) cb (count colB)
        c (max ca cb)
        colA (concat colA (repeat (- c ca) ""))
        colB (concat colB (repeat (- c cb) ""))]
    (map vector colA colB)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn rowmaker
  [cols]
  (->> cols
       (map #(concat % (repeat "")))
       (apply map vector)
       (take (->> cols
                  (map count)
                  (apply max)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer recursion to counting the number of items in collections. Here is my solution.

```
(defn row-maker
  [col-a col-b]
  (loop [acc []
         as (seq col-a)
         bs (seq col-b)]
    (if (or as bs)
      (recur (conj acc [(or (first as) "") (or (first bs) "")])
             (next as)
             (next bs))
      acc)))
```

Comment: This is a better answer as it avoids `concat`enating. `concat` builds `lazy-seq`'s that are thrown away in the end.

Comment: @muhuk Wrong, lazy-seqs don't hold onto their head. What is thrown away at the end is their head only. They do cost per step overhead though, but in Clojure 1.7. this can be eliminated with transducers instead of rewriting the entire thing with loop.

Comment: @muhuk Also absolute performance shouldn't be a measurement for the quality of an answer, only relative shoud. All answers perform in linear time. This answer is less readable, more difficult to refactor, more error prone in maintenance and it even lacks the idiomatic destructoring.

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick with the given example:

```
(defn rowMaker [v1 v2]
  (mapv vector (concat v1 (repeat "")) v2))

(rowMaker ["A1"] ["B1" "B2"])
;[["A1" "B1"] ["" "B2"]]
```

However, it doesn't work the other way round:

```
(rowMaker ["B1" "B2"] ["A1"])
;[["B1" "A1"]]
```

To make it work both ways, we are going to have to write a version of `mapv` that fills in for sterile sequences so long as any sequence is fertile. Here is a corresponding lazy version for `map`, which will work for infinite sequences too:

```
(defn map-filler [filler f & colls]
  (let [filler (vec filler)
        colls (vec colls)
        live-coll-map (->> colls
                           (map-indexed vector)
                           (filter (comp seq second))
                           (into {}))
        split (fn [lcm] (reduce
                         (fn [[x xm] [i coll]]
                           (let [[c & cs] coll]
                             [(assoc x i c) (if cs (assoc xm i cs) xm)]))
                         [filler {}]
                         lcm))]
    ((fn expostulate [lcm]
       (lazy-seq
        (when (seq lcm)
          (let [[this thoses] (split lcm)]
            (cons (apply f this) (expostulate thoses))))))
     live-coll-map)))
```

The idea is that you supply a `filler` sequence with one entry for each of the collections that follow. So we can now define your required `rowmaker` function thus:

```
(defn rowmaker [& colls]
  (apply map-filler (repeat (count colls) "") vector colls))
```

This will take any number of collections, and will fill in blank strings for exhausted collections.

```
(rowmaker ["A1"] ["B1" "B2"])
;(["A1" "B1"] ["" "B2"])

(rowmaker ["B1" "B2"] ["A1"])
;(["B1" "A1"] ["B2" ""])
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn make-row
  [cola colb r]
  (let [pad ""]
    (cond
      (and (not (empty? cola))
           (not (empty? colb))) (recur (rest cola)
                                       (rest colb)
                                       (conj r [(first cola) (first colb)]))
      (and (not (empty? cola))
           (empty? colb)) (recur (rest cola)
                                 (rest colb)
                                 (conj r [(first cola) pad]))
      (and (empty? cola)
           (not (empty? colb))) (recur (rest cola)
                                       (rest colb)
                                       (conj r [pad (first colb)]))
      :else r)))
```